# How to make a database for user content

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I'd like to ask you, how would you make a database for custom user content. I've got a web page which shows news via RSS feeds from a few websites, but I would like to be able to store "user settings" of feeds for each user who has an account and logs in. 
 For example:
User1 wants to see feeds 1, 2 and 4 after login.
User2 wants to see only feeds 2 and 5.
And so on. I've got a database with two tables, "members" and "feeds". I dont know how to connect them or create a new one which would handle the settings each user sets.
I've though of creating a table which would have a boolean type for each of the RSS feed and also a user ID and I would either display that feed if it would be "true" or no if "false", but I don't really know how to do it.
Can anyone help me somehow? Or point me to some tutorial for something similiar? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table that would have rows like this: `id, user_id, feed_id,mod-date;` no need to keep all the feeds for all the users with booleans in them, because you would have `number of users X number of feeds` in this table. My way you only have the rows that signal what each user wants to see. Insert and delete rows as needed.

then to see what each user wants to see do this:

```
Select f.feed from feed_table f
LEFT JOIN user_feed_table uft ON uft.user_id = (some user id)
WHERE f.id = uft.feed_id
```

or something to that extent

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it this way, it seems more logical than my first though :) ..